# How to list any gems that aren't dependencies (i.e., sort of like `brew leaves` in Homebrew)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, dependencies, homebrew, package-managers

I'm aware of `gem dependency` as a means to investigate a dependency graph, but I'm looking for something a little more straightforward. I only want to list gems that aren't dependencies of other gems.

In Homebrew, you can accomplish something similar with `brew leaves` - this lists packages that aren't dependencies of other packages. I mention this in case it's helpful in understanding what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've made a small shell script for that:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

GEMS_FILE=`mktemp`
DEPENDENCIES_FILE=`mktemp`

gem list -l | sed 's/ (.*//' | sort > $GEMS_FILE
cat $GEMS_FILE | xargs -n1 gem dependency -l --pipe | sed 's/ --version.*//' | sort -u > $DEPENDENCIES_FILE
comm -23 $GEMS_FILE $DEPENDENCIES_FILE
rm -f $GEMS_FILE $DEPENDENCIES_FILE
```

Also in a Gist form: https://gist.github.com/astyagun/290b783045afffb8190a0c75ab76d0fa

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for the `gem list` command.

If you're looking for gem help you can just `run gem --help`.